Quote or reference from an early Asimov 'Foundation' book concerning how poor maintenance (of a sidewalk?) indicated the decay of the Empire
Can anyone advise either a pointer to or the actual quote from one of the early Asimov Foundation books about how the simple poor maintenance (of a sidewalk, perhaps?) indicated the decay of  the Empire?
I recently read it but can't find it now….

This is Chapter 14 of Prelude to Foundation.

“There it is,” he said, pointing.
“I know, but let us move on to a boarding station. There are more cars
there and it is easier to get on.”
Once they were safely ensconced in an Expressway car, Seldon turned to
Hummin and said, “What amazes me is how quiet the Expressways are. I
realize that they are mass-propelled by an electromagnetic field, but
it seems quiet even for that.” He listened to the occasional metallic
groan as the car they were on shifted against its neighbors.
“Yes, it’s a marvelous network,” said Hummin, “but you don’t see it at
its peak. When I was younger, it was quieter than it is now and there
are those who say that there wasn’t as much as a whisper fifty years
ago—though I suppose we might make allowance for the idealization of
nostalgia.”
“Why isn’t it that way now?”
“Because it isn’t maintained properly. I told you about decay.”
Seldon frowned. “Surely, people don’t sit around and say, ‘We’re
decaying. Let’s let the Expressways fall apart.’ ”
“No, they don’t. It’s not a purposeful thing. Bad spots are patched,
decrepit coaches refurbished, magnets replaced. However, it’s done in
more slapdash fashion, more carelessly, and at greater intervals.
There just aren’t enough credits available.”
“Where have the credits gone?”
“Into other things. We’ve had centuries of unrest.


Ah! That must have been it! I don't have nor have yet to read 'Prelude to Foundation'. Thank you so very much! Cheers!
